# Cut road polygon layer into small polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, editing

I need a model to split that road stream at the intersections to have a road polygon to every street. I have tried to buffer the streets and use the buffer to cut the road polygon but it failed and I don't want to do it manually by the cut polygons have more than 1200 streets here it will take time and effort.

I want to split the purple polygon to smaller polygons that surround every street with its road polygon.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.

[image: the purple polygon is the one I want to cut to smaller polygons]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Do you want to split the Purple polygons or the green lines at the intersections?

Comment: the purple polygons

Comment: i want to split the purple polygon to smaller polygons that to surround every street with its road polygon.

Comment: Use Euclidean allocation, convert to polygons, clip by road polygons.